# Error for partition in KAFKA

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

Suddenly several topics became an Under Replicated
In the logs such errors
what should I do?

```
May 04 14:17:23 2kafka01.rtty.in kafka-server-start.sh[149443]: kafka.common.NotAssignedReplicaException: Leader 1 failed to record follower 2's position -1 since the replica is not recognized to be one of the assigned replicas 1,3,4 for partition [impression,3].
May 04 14:17:23 2kafka01.rtty.in kafka-server-start.sh[149443]: at kafka.cluster.Partition.updateReplicaLogReadResult(Partition.scala:249)
May 04 14:17:23 2kafka01.rtty.in kafka-server-start.sh[149443]: at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$updateFollowerLogReadResults$2.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:905)
May 04 14:17:23 2kafka01.rtty.in kafka-server-start.sh[149443]: at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$updateFollowerLogReadResults$2.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:902)
May 04 14:17:23 2kafka01.rtty.in kafka-server-start.sh[149443]: at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
May 04 14:17:23 2kafka01.rtty.in kafka-server-start.sh[149443]: at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
May 04 14:17:23 2kafka01.rtty.in kafka-server-start.sh[149443]: at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.updateFollowerLogReadResults(ReplicaManager.scala:902)
May 04 14:17:23 2kafka01.rtty.in kafka-server-start.sh[149443]: at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.fetchMessages(ReplicaManager.scala:475)
May 04 14:17:23 2kafka01.rtty.in kafka-server-start.sh[149443]: at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleFetchRequest(KafkaApis.scala:523)
May 04 14:17:23 2kafka01.rtty.in kafka-server-start.sh[149443]: at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:79)
May 04 14:17:23 2kafka01.rtty.in kafka-server-start.sh[149443]: at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:60)
May 04 14:17:23 2kafka01.rtty.in kafka-server-start.sh[149443]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

all KAFKA brokers will choose one as controller broker, which can get by zookeeper znode `/controller`, try restart this broker. More information see [apache kafka wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Controller+Internals).
If can restart the KAFKA cluster (all brokers), is recommended.